# On ubuntu when I run sublime text from the terminal it will open two instances

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2

I was trying to get sublime to work from the terminal. I was having issues setting up the symlink for some reason so I tried a couple different things to get it to work, finally when I got it to work and I ran the first command of `subl <myFile>` it opened it. However it opened two instances of it. also, in the terminal it seems like it is still running something. Continues to say:

`(sublime_text:5910): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 5148 was not found when attempting to remove it`

and continues to print the above line fairly regularly, if I exit out of both instances of sublime it will stop running the process.

Something to note as well.  I am able to open up sublime with no issues if I find it via the launcher search. When I type in `which sublime` it gives me `/usr/bin/sublilme` Which I think if where it should be.

And lastly, I'm quite new to ubuntu, my new job uses it so now I need to get to know it, as well as new to programming in general.

P.S. I was trying to post this in the ask ubuntu section but it refused to post the question as it said I could only post something every 20 minutes. (This is my first question ever asked on that section...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a famous bug in Sublime 2 as it remember your last session and always opens it.

You need to edit Packages/User/Global.sublime-settings you need to make sure the below preferences are there (remember_open_files)

```
{
  "hot_exit": false,
  "remember_open_files": false
}
```

For more information read [this](https://github.com/SeanHolden/Wiki/wiki/Sublime%3A-disable-loading-of-last-session).

Comment: That fixed it about 90% of the way. It only opens one instance now, however when I run ```subl <myFile>``` something runs continuously on the terminal with ```(sublime_text:19009): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6367 was not found when attempting to remove it``` popping up every now and then, is it supposed to do this?

Comment: that sounds normal to me, have you tried & at the end to push it to background? like: subl <myFile> &